# Reducing font size of legends using Plot in R and shifting to bottom left?

Tags: r, plot, font-size

How can I reduce the font size in my plot and shift to the bottom left? Following is my code:

```
plot(Roc(list("A"=lrm.met,"B"=lrm.cyssvscys,"C"=lrm.cyss, "D"=lrm.cys, "E"=lrm.metvsmetsulfo, "F"=lrm.metsulfo, "G"=lrm.allan)),legend=TRUE,auc=TRUE)
title(main = "Title")
```

Thanks in advance!

[image: Plot]

Comment: since the font size question has an answer, and the remaining question is how to shift the legend to the bottom left, can you edit the question to focus on that?  There's no reason to ask "how do I do A & B?" if "how do I do A?" is already answered well.  If the other question about font size is not a duplicate, please explain how yours is different.  Thanks!

Comment: @iconoclast I'm confused by the portion whereby I used legend = T, AUC = T. Read the previous answers provided by Sotos, but however, Im not able to reduce the font size even after attempting the answers. Hence, my question here.

Comment: sorry, I can't help you with your code.  I'm only offering to vote for reopening if you make the changes I mentioned.